# Adsense overlapping facebook like box

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

on this page:
http://intolerable-absurdities.com/i-wonder-where-grizzlies-are-keeping-their-lunch-boxes/

Adsense ad on the right (or on mobile devices at the bottom) sometimes overlaps the facebook like box so that the adsense ad is right above the like box so part of the like box is covered. 
I simply can't find the issue and would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not seeing the error but maybe try adding a clear fix to the div above it? Like so: `<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 sidetoppad fbbox clearfix">`

Answer (score 0):

Add a clear fix to the div above it Like so:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 sidetoppad fbbox clearfix">
```

Also it could be that the Google Ads code positions the widget before the iframe content loads and declares its height. If that's the case, then you could add this rule to make sure the iframe's containing element has enough height at all times:

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
    min-height: 338px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Didn't happen for a few minutes but now the ad is above the like box again. Like here:intolerable-absurdities.com/above.png

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Can you give me exact OS, browser version, and steps to reproduce the bug? I see it in the PNG, but I need to see the code when that occurs.

Comment: You could try giving the iframe widget containing element a min-height. See the edited content I added above.

Comment: Just implemented your added css. But I don't know if it works, yet. The thing is, that I also can't always reproduce it. But when it happens, it happens on: mac os mavericks, Chrome Browser 32.0.1700.107. Window size doesn't seem to influence it.

Comment: I've seen every comic on the site. I cannot reproduce the problem. Next time it happens, right click and inspect elements to open up dev tools. Take a close look in there. at what's going on, try turning styles on & off and/or add some styles and figure out what's happening. Sorry can't help more, but I can't re-create the bug.